# Report Services: Controlling page breaks inside a table

Tags: reporting-services, page-break

I'm using a table on my report to present the data. Since it was a lot of data and I wanted to print the report on a A4 page, I split each row into 3 different rows.

My problem is when the report goes to the second page, I want it to break before or after the 3 rows.

example:

---

name                  age
address
contact

---

name                  age
address
contact

---

name                  age
address
 *** page break ***
contact

---

this is what normally happens. I want to ensure that the page break only happens on the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ended up creating a subreport to represent each item.

I looked for the KeepTogether property but that's probably only for reporting services 2008 (I'm using 2005).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple strategies to follow:

- The KeepTogether is useful in this case
- If you want it to fit on one page only try adjusting page margins, padding, font size, line height to make the report render more compactly
- Another alternative is to create a table group on the person, and from the group properties (edit group) check the page break at end property. this way you can have each group on a separate page

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have the table in a subreport, you must also **Right Click -> Format Object -> `Uncheck` Keep object together**.

This was the step that did it for me after I unchecked **Keep object together** on the table and the subreport details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried 'Keep together' and it didn't work. After a long time of changing and trying many things the one thing that did the job was reducing the bottom margin of a page.