# When we add page break on first table the second table is shown on last page

Tags: report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In my report I have two tables on the body. I have added a page break only in the first table. When we print the report, items are correctly printed but second table is shown on last page.

E.g

```
   page-1
      Item 1
      Item 2  table1
      Item 3
   Page-2
      Item 4
      Item 5  table1
      Item 6
   Page 3
      Item 7  table1
      Item 8
   Page 4
      Taxes prints  table2
```

But I want:

```
   page-1
      Item 1
      Item 2  table1
      Item 3
   Page-2
      Item 4
      Item 5  table1
      Item 6
   Page 3
      Item 7  table1
      Item 8
      Taxes prints  table2
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If table2 is printed last and your make a page break after table1, then by logic table2 is printed on a new page.

Comment: What do you use, SSRS or MorphX reports?

Comment: Hello, I am using SSRS report in ax 2012. Suppose in my report total 8 items in table 1. I want only 5 items per page in that case 5 items in first page and 3 items in second page. and also i want taxes(table 2) are printed on second page not a third page .... Please help me....

Comment: How and where did you make your page break?

Comment: i want to add page break in table1 for only 5 items per page

Comment: How and where did you make your page break?

Comment: As i said i want to add page break in table1 for only 5 items per page

Comment: You said "I have added a page break only in the first table.", how did you do that? Please read the comments carefully.

Comment: I have added a new group on table1 then goto group properties and write this expression=iif(Floor((Rownumber(Nothing)-1)/5), False , True) and check mark the also of the start of the group and also of the end of a group...

Comment: Try to remove the check mark "of the end of group".

Answer (score 0):

See this question about controlling page breaks:
[Report Services: Controlling page breaks inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177005/report-services-controlling-page-breaks-inside-a-table)

Also the spec may be of help: [Pagination in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255207.aspx)